# How to get total number of rows in all sections | Swift

Tags: swift

Essentially I have a table with rows split into multiple section. Each section has a different amount of rows and I would like to get the total number of rows that are in the table as a whole.

I have tried using `numberOfRowsInSection` but this only displays the number of rows in a particular section.

**The table data is coming from JSON with the following structure:**

```
struct Section {
    let name : String
    var items : [Portfolio]
}

struct Portfolio: Decodable {

    let people: String
    let numbers: String

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case people, numbers
    }
```

Comment: So you have an array of `Section`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have an array of `Section`s, you can get the total of all `items` by using `reduce`:

```
func totalItems(_ sections: [Section]) -> Int {
    return sections.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.items.count }
}
```

Comment: Total Number of Rows including section header


 let totalRow = Section.reduce(0) { $0 + $1. items.count } + Section.count